# Where to get Buyer info such as buyer email, name etc for pending order or cancel orders in Amazon mws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I am using **Amazon MWS Orders API for fetching the orders** so for that
I hit the ListOrder API that gives me the order details which have status as:

> pending, shipped, unshipped, cancel

I got the buyer information where orderStatus is shipped,unshipped. As stated in **documentation of Amazon orderList:-**

> For unshipped, Partiallyshipped, Shipped orderStatus we get the
> following information for Buyer i.e:-
> BuyerEmail, BuyerName, Shipping Address, OrderTotal.

But I am integrating my Application for handle my Amazon order pragmatically .And on that case I want as any new order is placed than all the info of that order with buyer details like buyer-name, email,Shipping address etc are also there **so that I know which buyer place a new order** same in case of cancel so that I can show them on my Application.

**So please let me know how can I get those buyer details for pending orders as well as for canceled orders**.Is there any API or attribute I need to send or I am missing something or should I need to generate report every time to achieve that.

Comment: @VladimirNul i don't found anything to achieve this because in amazon mws orders API documentation it is clearly mentioned that API will not going to return the buyerInfo for pending orders, that's why i asked question for that.

Comment: So if they say it's not possible, why are you still trying to do that?

Comment: @VladimirNul as mayank suggested give the answer if you know otherwise no need to become James bond(007) or  iron man(Robert Downey Jr) because you can't .

Comment: i also want the answer for that i am also facing issue

Comment: <FulfillmentChannel>MFN</FulfillmentChannel>
<OrderStatus>Pending</OrderStatus> ETC ETC ETC

Comment: @cartalot thanks for reply could you please explain in little bit detail where should i use this MFN and other

Comment: @Parveenyadav Did you get the buyer email id for completed orders? I tried the same API and in ListOrder I am getting all the buyer details except the correct email ID.  The email ID I get for buyers looks like  x9qfjgc65b561b9@marketplace.amazon.com. Can you help here?

Answer (score 2):

Your question(s) : "So please let me know how can i get those buyer details for pending orders as well as for canceled orders.Is there any API or attribute i need to send ..."
There is no way, API or otherwise, to get buyer information for any pending or buyer cancelled orders.

"or i am missing something"
Believing the documentation

"or should i need to generate report every time to achieve that."
You can't achieve this ... report or Orders API call.